# css, jquery issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was playing with Infogrid on my [site](http://bit.ly/aS877j).
I added a header, a footer and added some text on the last block of iron man.
As you can see the footer doesn't show up and the text of the last block is cut off.
Now if you remove overflow:hidden; on the body, html the footer shows up but the text is still cut off.
Any idea on how this the footer could show up without the scrollbar (so overflow:hidden; has to stay) and how to get the text of the last block to show up entirely? 
Thanks in advance and have fun :)
wadada

Comment: here is the link of the original infogrid source code
http://www.webappers.com/2010/03/24/grid-accordion-expands-to-reasonable-width-automatically/

Comment: Seems fine on Chrome 4.1

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're taking the wrong approach.

First of all, the text of the last block is NOT cut off on Firefox... but it is completely dependent on the resolution of the browser.

Basically, your CSS is saying: I don't care if there's more content, don't scroll. Taking this control away from the user isn't a good idea.

I'm not trying to lecture here, but I'm just stating that by artificially limiting what your users can do, it doesn't allow for the thousands of different browsers and configurations your users have.

One way you can prevent content from getting cut off is by setting a max height on your dd elements. This way, the scroll bars only go on necessary elements.

```
.info-col dd {
   max-height:100px;
   overflow-y:auto;
   overflow-x:none;
}
```

This will NOT work in IE6, however...

Comment: thanks for your reply atomiton, i understand your point but i'd like to find a way to keep the scroll-bar away, it just doesn't look like i'd like it to be :)

Comment: If you don't add more content than the height of the page, you'll never get the scroll-bar ( assuming they're set at auto ). The only reasonable way to assure users can see the content and not get the scroll bars is set a max height on each box and apply the scroll bar there. Alternatively, you can implement a jQuery scroll bar and format it how you like. Here's a site that uses it for example: http://www.balancedplanets.com/aboutbook/

Comment: i see, jquery scroll and your previous seems like a good option - thanks atomiton

Comment: There are other options, depending on what you want to accomplish. Is your goal to display all the content on one page without scroll bars? If so, you have to think about users who will access your site on netbooks, mobile devices or non-maximized windows. Removing the scroll-bar for those users will frustrate them. They usually have limited screen real-estate to work with.